# Numpy : clip/cut 2d masked array

Tags: python, numpy

From a masked 2d array like this: (`x` = `--`)

```
x x x x
x 5 6 x
x x x x
x x 9 x
```

How can I get: (confining the edges as much as possible until reaching a number)

```
5 6
x x 
x 9
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the slice you want for a generic situation:

```
import numpy as np
si, se = np.where(~x.mask)
x = x[si.min():si.max() + 1, se.min():se.max() + 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use slicing :-)

```
slice = x[1:, 1:-1]
```

You can also trim the edges:

```
while all(x.mask[0, :]): x = x[1:, :]
while all(x.mask[-1, :]): x = x[:-1, :]
while all(x.mask[:, 0]): x = x[:, 1:]
while all(x.mask[:, -1]): x = x[:, :-1]
```

Comment: I believe OP wants to confine the edges as much as possible until reaching a number, so this doesn't answer it

Comment: @Azimo still doesn't answer the question